# How to get one value of few buttons? "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property"

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a value of one of four buttons I created. I tried to do this as in code bellow and it works fine when I use console.log however when I just want to return the value I get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at direction (script.js:16)"

Any ideas how to deal with it?

```
<div class="dirButtons">
    <input type="button" id="right" class="button" name="direction" value="to right" onclick="direction(this)">
    <input type="button" id="left" class="button" name="direction" value="to left" onclick="direction(this)">
    <input type="button" id="bottom" class="button" name="direction" value="to bottom" onclick="direction(this)">
    <input type="button" id="top" class="button"name="direction" value="to top" onclick="direction(this)">
</div>
```

```
function direction(event){
    console.log(document.getElementById(event.id).value);   
}
```

Comment: return what value? Not sure how return would work with that code.

Comment: You're passing "this", which is the reference to the element, but in your script, you are treating it like an event. Why not just pass this.value?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `function(this)` in the element's `onclick event` what you're really passing is the element, not the event, so you'd like to access the `element's` `value` directly instead.

```js
function direction(element){
    console.log(element.value);   
}
```

```html
<div class="dirButtons">
    <input type="button" id="right" class="button" name="direction" value="to right" onclick="direction(this)">
    <input type="button" id="left" class="button" name="direction" value="to left" onclick="direction(this)">
    <input type="button" id="bottom" class="button" name="direction" value="to bottom" onclick="direction(this)">
    <input type="button" id="top" class="button"name="direction" value="to top" onclick="direction(this)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get it now however when instead of `console.log(element.value); ` I make `return element.value;` and try use this value in another function I still get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at direction"

Comment: That's because the function is being called from another context (which means an element has to call it to successfully retrieve the element's value). You can try to update your question and include the rest of the code to see how we can modify it.

Beforehand I can tell you that you could save the last value called on the function into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function direction(event){
    console.log(event.value);   
}
```

This should preform what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly from what I can see, that should work fine but for some reason the `this` that you're passing to your event handler is undefined. That being said, what you're doing is pretty redundant and bad practice for a couple of reasons.

1. There is no need to pass the target element to the event handler, as this is already included in the event object.
2. You should not name an event handler parameter `event`, as this overrides the event object that is included in event handler context ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value)).

So in this case it is best to change to:

```
<div class="dirButtons">
    <input type="button" id="right" class="button" name="direction" value="to right" onclick="direction()">
    <input type="button" id="left" class="button" name="direction" value="to left" onclick="direction()">
    <input type="button" id="bottom" class="button" name="direction" value="to bottom" onclick="direction()">
    <input type="button" id="top" class="button"name="direction" value="to top" onclick="direction()">
</div>
```

```
function direction(){
    console.log(event.target.value);   
}
```

Comment: Now it works just fine! Now I see what mistakes I've made. Thanks!